# Prevent protection of questions when it would have no effect

Tags: feature-request, protected-questions

In the dozens of times I've checked, I have never once found a *single* valid use of "protect question" in the list of [recently protected questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools), outside of those questions automatically protected by the Community user. This isn't hyperbole, I have *never* seen it used correctly by a [~15k rep user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) who has recently unlocked the ability. Often these users will protect quite a few questions, presumably because they have *no idea* what protection is or when they should use it.

[Protection prevents answer by new/anonymous users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), and in every case I've reviewed I have failed to find a single answer by a new user which would have been prevented by protection, so I've unprotected the question.

This seems like a process we can automate. **I propose that we disallow protection of a question which has no answers that would have been prevented by protection.**

I can't really see any case where somebody would have fore-knowledge of which kind of question is likely to receive lots of "me too" and "thanks" answers before they start coming in, so allowing people to protect questions before they show any sign of needing it seems like it can only lead to this kind of abuse.

**To clarify:**

Protection: **good.**

Protecting arbitrary questions that don't need it: **bad.**

We can automatically detect and prevent the second case. That is my proposal.

**Examples**

Posting a few examples as I spot them in the list of recently protected questions.

- [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch)

  This question hasn't received any spam, "me too" or "thanks" answers, and it's been around since **2009**. There was no reason to protect it.
- 8 Questions protected by the same person (with 15007 rep...) and *none* of them needed it:

  - [How to resize NSImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949250/how-to-resize-nsimage)
  - [UIView with a Dashed line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091916/uiview-with-a-dashed-line)
  - [UILabel with text struck through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133014/uilabel-with-text-struck-through)
  - [Add subview with UIAlertVIew like animation,with a bouncing effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250349/add-subview-with-uialertview-like-animation-with-a-bouncing-effect)
  - [How to make an underlined text in UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122207/how-to-make-an-underlined-text-in-uilabel)
  - [iOS - Facebook Connect logout not deleting login details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649450/ios-facebook-connect-logout-not-deleting-login-details)
  - [iOS Universal Development – Use of Tilde Sign (~) in Xib File and Image Name for differentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742930/ios-universal-development-use-of-tilde-sign-in-xib-file-name-for-different)
  - [Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios)

    These were "protected by Prince - Peaceful Warrior 50 mins ago", but have no recent activity or any spam/thanks/me-too answers that would necessitate protection
- [Is CSS turing complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497146/is-css-turing-complete)

  No activity since April 2013, several down-voted answers but none that could be argued as "spam/thanks/me too" answers
- [How to implement semaphore thread communication in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488806/how-to-implement-semaphore-thread-communication-in-perl)

  No activity since 2012, no spam answers at all
- [Check if a directory exists in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script), [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

  No reason to have protected either of these. They're both popular questions, but they aren't getting any recent traffic or spammy posts.

  Actually, this last user appears to have unprotected and re-protected several questions, 
  for unknown reasons.
- [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

  Just another old question protected for no reason. It contains a few downvoted answers, but none of them were spam. One of them is a **legitimate attempt** to answer the question by a 1 rep user, which would have been prevented by protection

Comment: Case in point, I just unprotected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999138/design-pattern-to-manage-a-connection-to-remote-apis which has only two answers, one of which is a deleted link-only answer by the questions author, who has 200+ rep. There has been no activity in that question since August. There was absolutely *no* reason to protect this question, yet a 55k user decided to do so anyways.

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly?"  It is *already* automated; question protection gets applied by the Community User when two or more 1-rep answers get deleted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm specifically asking to limit the ability to protect questions to those that show signs of needing it, where protecting the question would have prevented at least one of the current deleted/undeleted answers from being posted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm asking for this restriction because I thought it would be more popular than simply removing the ability to manually protect questions, which I think would be the better solution. Users don't need the ability, and I have only ever seen it used incorrectly.

Comment: 10 rep is a really low bar, y'know.  Some of us like the ability to preempt incoming bad answers, but I am sensitive to the current gestalt of only using it when necessary.

Comment: I've seen it used *many* times to great effect.  The simplest explanation for you thinking it having no effect is because it worked.  It in fact stopped me-too answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure what your point is. Are you saying that we should allow people to protect arbitrary questions because protection is so easy to circumvent, by gaining 10 rep?

Comment: I am saying that we gave people this privilege; let them use it.  Despite your protestations, I've never actually seen anyone illegitimately abuse it, and I think protection benefits from community involvement.

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately, I can only cite my most recent example, but I assure you, no "me too"/"thanks" answers were prevented by protecting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999138/design-pattern-to-manage-a-connection-to-remote-apis. That question has seen no activity in almost a year, and this is the regular pattern I see: Old questions with no recent activity protected for no discernible reason.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd argue that incorrectly applied protection prevents legitimate answers for new/anonymous users, more than it "benefits from community involvement"

Comment: Yeah, you're right about that question; it doesn't have all that many views (although it appears to be a contentious one; it was closed, deleted, undeleted and reopened).  Just unprotect those, like you have been.

Comment: I have heard that argument, but I don't think it's true.  At least not to the degree that you're expressing here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The crux of my feature request is that those are literally the *only* kind of question I come across in the "recently protected" list. Questions with low/no recent activity with only valid answers that have no need of protection. Why do we allow people to protect these questions when we can programatically see that there is absolutely no need to do so? I don't believe there is any way of predicting a question will need protection *before* it needs protection, so why allow it?

Comment: "That question has seen no activity in almost a year".  Right, protecting it stopped it from getting re-activated.  Only editing it could do so.  *It worked*.  Your assertion that it wouldn't have gotten me-too answers without protection is completely unprovable.

Comment: @meagar: How many counter-examples do you want?  Here's one that *really* needed protection: http://stackoverflow.com/q/671118

Comment: @HansPassant ... *What*? So we should protect all old questions now, so they don't get bumped? That isn't at all what protection is for.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That question supports my point, not yours. It **needed** protection, so it was protected. Every single deleted answer was posted **before** the question was protected. I'm not arguing that we should do away with protection, I'm saying that we shouldn't be able to apply it before its needed.

Comment: I looked at the same list that you did (recently protected).  The first 10 in that list were all protected by Community.  The 11th one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/mininum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index was protected by a community leader.  It has 91,000 views and two deleted nonsense answers on it.

Comment: @HansPassant I missed this part: "Your assertion that it wouldn't have gotten me-too answers without protection is completely unprovable" **Are you serious?** That question received no spam/thanks/me-too answers for almost a *year*, then it was protected for less than 8 hours, then I unprotected it. You think in that 8 hour window protection prevented all sorts of answers?

Comment: The next 5 were all protected by Community.  I'm sorry, but I don't think that makes your case.  I just don't see an actionable problem here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Again. [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/mininum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index) was protected **after** it showed signs of needing it. I can't state this any clearer: I'm not arguing against protection. I'm really, really not. I'm arguing against protecting questions before they have received answers that would have been prevented by protection.

Comment: Do you have any other examples of questions that should not have been protected?  The list I get in the tools only has about 15 questions in it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I don't. If you check my account history (if you're able to?) for questions I've unprotected, you'll see a bunch.

Comment: I don't see a tool or tab that will give me that, and SE has (correctly) excluded the text "Protected by user" from Google, so I can't use that either.

Comment: Then I've no further evidence to offer; in the future I'll note down questions which have been obviously protected in error before I unprotect them, but historically I didn't see a need to do so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Actually, [it hasn't](http://www.google.com/search?q="protected+by+Robert+Harvey") (and the only way it *could* do that is by [cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking), which [Google really frowns upon](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604723)). However, you obviously can't find questions someone has *unprotected* that way.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Ah, I see.  Well that means that meagar never protects any questions, which I guess means that he doesn't believe in preemptively protecting questions at all.

Comment: Lies! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958351/facebooks-mobile-app-site-horizontal-slide-menu-jquery-plugin  Though, I have no memory of protecting these questions.

Comment: @meagar: The reason I decided to protect the question in your first comment, was a tad different from a classic protection case. That question was recently deleted and undeleted. And to ensure that the next moderator or users who may come and see it, see that it is protected, meaning someone actually cares about it. Sure, you can yell. But that's one way I know to show that this question is useful enough to be kept alive. Is it *the* best way? I don't know. But it is definitely a way. So not to prevent it from being answered or flooded, but to raise a warning bell for potential deleters.

Comment: In fact, it's not that the question itself was inherently useful. But the answer given to it is very good and informative.

Comment: @SecondRikudo That isn't what protection is for, and it doesn't effectively serve the purpose of indicating that "somebody cares" about a given question.

Comment: I have a confession. I've protected maybe like 2-4 questions since gaining the privilege (if I remember correctly). In maybe around 2 of those cases, it was on a question that I also voted to close (probably because it was too broad), in order to prevent answers to a "bad question" that I expected to be closed soon. It's a questionable use of the privilege, so I'll stop, but I'm just bringing it up as an example.

Comment: [A more recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch). This question has received neither spam, "me too" or "thanks" answers, and it's been around since **2009**. There was no reason to protect it.

Comment: @meagar that looks familiar, was I the person who protected it?

Comment: @Cupcake [Nope](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1519006/revisions).

Comment: @meagar: That question has nearly half a million views, and one answer by a 1 rep user that was deleted.  I'd say it's a perfect candidate for protection, though I grant you that there haven't been all that many problems on it so far.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not sure which question you're talking about

Comment: [A more recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch).

Comment: @RobertHarvey That question has a single answer by a 1 rep user which was a legitimate attempt to help. It wasn't a good answer, but it definitely wasn't a spam/thanks/me-too answer.

Comment: @meagar: On the other hand, I don't see brand new 1 rep experts clamoring to add their really important bit to that question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That doesn't mean we should preemptively cut off their ability to contribute.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the unprotection of the branch question. The only reason why you don't see any spam there is *because* it was protected early. And even then, there are scores of deleted duplicate/non-answers from the people who did have 10 rep. If anything, the protection threshold should be even higher for high-profile questions.

Comment: @mysticial: Not exactly.  The [timeline on that question](http://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/timeline/1519006) indicates that it was only protected for 4 hours before meagar unprotected it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Check page 2 of the revisions. It was protected on the second day of its existence: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/revisions?page=2 Also, I can't see your link since it looks like it's mod-only.

Comment: @Mysticial: Thought you were talking about the [How to create a remote branch in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch) question.  I've put protection back on the Branch Prediction question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My fault too. I didn't realize there was another "branch" question here. :D I should've clarified.

Comment: Dammit.  How do you get a timeline link on a question with no revisions?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Just drop the `admin/`. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1519006/timeline

Comment: Cool.  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1519006/revisions works too, for this purpose.

Answer (score 13):

You are requesting that we "Prevent protection of questions when it would have no effect".

Clearly, protecting questions does have an effect -- especially on high-traffic ones:

**(More than 5 months later..)**

I protected two of the questions you are using as examples.

Let's look at [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)

> This question hasn't received any spam, "me too" or "thanks" answers, and it's been around since 2009. There was no reason to protect it.

As [Robert Harvey said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253132/prevent-protection-of-questions-when-it-would-have-no-effect#comment13072_253132), with over half a million views, this question was a perfect candidate for protection.

The [Community ♦ user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) automatically [protected the question 2 months later](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1519006/revisions):

[image]

---

I also protected one of your other examples, [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window).

[image]

Just last week, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26234922/2680216) by a user with 1 reputation was deleted. If the question wasn't unprotected, this wouldn't have been an issue.

[image]

---

I agree with a few of the other examples you posted, but i'd say that *these* questions were rightfully protected.

I think you're being overly pedantic about this, though. I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: Conversely, both of those questions would have been equally well "protected" if we simply didn't let 1-rep users post answers to *any* popular questions. Obviously this is a terrible idea. You cannot guess what questions are going to get non-answer answers from 1 rep users.

Comment: @meagar - I agree. How do you know when to protect a question anyways? (i.e., What is substituted as a *popular* question - number of views, answers, comments, votes, etc?). I think the 'protected' question system is broken, and I don't think there is a universal solution to this. When it comes down to it, the community is the exception catcher.