# Protecting/unprotecting a question doesn't cause link to revision history to appear

Tags: bug, edits, revision-history

This comes out of [this semi-related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253132/prevent-protection-of-questions-when-it-would-have-no-effect).

I've noticed that, in the revision history of a question, protection/unprotection are visible in as distinct events. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12091916/revisions

However, in questions which haven't been edited before, the revision history link doesn't appear, so there is no evidence that a question was protected/unprotected, and no easy way to check if it was. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949250/how-to-resize-nsimage) was protected and then unprotected, and there is no link to its [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11949250/revisions) displayed.

For the sake of consistency, should we should show a link to the revision history if a question has been protected/unprotected, since these appear as events in the revision history of a question?

Comment: Consistency is a very important feature, and I doubt there's any advantage to the current behavior sufficient to counter that.

Comment: But they're just that - events. The link to the history is to tell you it was *modified*. Other events like closing, reopening, (un)locking, and (un)deleting also do not cause that link to appear.

Comment: @user7294900 You should [ask a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) rather than post a question in the comments below somebody else's answer.

Comment: Err, never mind, I see [you did shortly after the comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374892/how-can-i-see-my-protecting-history).